# Magento2 Custom Option Select field Dropdown Loading

Tags: magento2, product, custom-options

Can any one help me to When **i select second time dropdown Custom options** Its Loading **continuously not stopping in Magento2** Product Custom options admin

Please find the Screenshot below.

[image]

Magento2.1.3 no console.log errors

Comment: Which magento version? Any console log?